# Why Force IDE is not downloading System Administrator Profile?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, ide, eclipse

In my Package.xml file, I have included all the profiles as shown below:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

And when I right click on the profiles folder and select 'Refresh from Server', It does not download the System Administrator profile but everything else..

What mistake I am doing here? Somebody please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Admin.profile vs System Administrator. If you still cannot locate it then make sure it is listed in the Add/Remove Metadata selections.

Comment: Oh..I thought that file name would be `System Administrator.Profile`